# Suppose we have an invertible matrix $A$ and we want to prove that there are matrices $B$ such that $AB-BA=A^2$. Is this proof correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given that $A$ is an invertible matrix, we want to find whether there are matrices $B$ such that $AB-BA=A^2$.

Here is my proof. Is it correct?
$$\begin{array}{c}AB - BA = A^2 \Rightarrow\\  
AB = (A+B)A\Rightarrow\\
AB = A(A +B).\end{array}$$ 
Letting $G=A^{-1}$, we have
$$\begin{array}{c}GAB =GA(A+B)\Rightarrow\\
B=A+B \Rightarrow\\
A=0.\end{array}$$

Comment: Does "reversible" mean "invertible"?

Comment: It is not clear what your argument is a proof of. You seem to conclude that $A=0$. What that this mean? Are there such matrices $B$, or not? Anyway, your proof has a serious flaw, in line 3, where you say that $(A+B)A=A(A+B)$.

Comment: (I changed "reversible" for "invertible" and "proof" for "prove", and formatted the text somewhat. Feel free to revert the changes, of course.)

Comment: it is given that matrix A is not a zero matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, every matrix $X$ satisfying $XB-BX=X^2$ must be nilpotent, i.e., cannot be invertible.
See Proposition $2.2$ in the paper [On the matrix equation $XA-AX=X^p$](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_20_matrix_equ.pdf).

Comment: More generally, if $[A,B]$ commutes with $A$, $[A,B]$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $tr(AB-BA)=0$ but in general $tr(A^2) \neq 0$.